# Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have code like this:

```
<div class="row"
     ng-repeat="x in orders|orderBy:'order_id'| filter:{ paid: '0' } ">
    <div class="col left">
        {{changeTableIdtoName(x.table_id)}}
    </div>
```

In app.js:

```
$scope.changeTableIdtoName = function changeTableIdtoName(id) {
    var url = "http://my.duangwifi.cn/yii2-basic/web/index.php?r=duangorder/resttable/view&id=" + id;
    //console.log("url",url);
    $http.get(url)
    .success(function (response)
    {
        console.log("changeTableIdtoName",response);
        console.log("response.name",response.name);
        return response.name;
    });
    }
```

It's said "Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting"

Where is the problem? thanks.

Comment: how many elements are there in `orders`? `changeTableIdtoName(x.table_id)` is evaluating for each digest cycle

Comment: Try adding the `track by` expression to your `ng-repeat`, e.g. `ng-repeat="x in orders track by $index | ..."`. Does that make a difference?

Comment: less than 100 elements, and for filter:{ paid: '0' }, there is only 1 element.

Comment: @muenchdo, it's said "Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: 0"

Comment: Hm, seems strange that this error occurs when adding `track by`... Can you create a Plunker so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: i failed to create Plunker....